# Creating Eclipse CSS themes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I never done any eclipse plugin development, so, the concept is a bit foreign to me. Anyways, I wish to create a simple eclipse theme, and reading this [blog post](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/) , which is about creating eclipse themes, pretty much summarized the following

> But if you want to play with it, you only need to write a plug-in,
>   create a CSS file and use the org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme
>   extension point to point to your file. If you export your plug-in,
>   place it in the “dropins” folder of your Eclipse installation and your
>   styling is available.

I proceeded to the [actual article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html) , but here the fact that I never done any plugin development for eclipse got me a bit confused about certain aspects of this article.

I created a new plugin, with a activator. Now the first bit that gets me stuck is in the parts about extension points. He skips the bit about setting up the product and the appname property, I guesses it needed to be something like the following for me

> ```
> <plugin>    
>   <extension
>      point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
>   <product
>         application="mythemetest.Activator"
>         name="mythemetest">
>      <property
>            name="appName"
>            value="mythemetest">
>      </property>
>      <property
>            name="applicationCSS"
>            value="platform:/plugin/mythemetest/css/default.css ">
>      </property>
>   </product>
> ```

Running this application will not start up a new eclipse themed using the default.css, so im doing something wrong. I'm guessing its in regards to the product element above.

Can anybody help me out here? :)

Comment: You did look at this: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?

Comment: yes i know of that site. unfortunately, nothing on that site will help with the question above though (since the site is all about colour themes for the code editor, not styling the whole of eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Eclipse 4 Chrome Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UJgPMyHx4z8), there you can edit the CSS directly and don't need to do the plugin programming part around the styling.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried the chrome theme (and I used the "CSS Editor" plugin as well). However, I am still interested in solving the original problem